# How to get indexPath.row of tableView which is currently being displayed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, nsarray

I have a tableView with many values.

I want to get the first `indexPath.row` value of the table which is being displayed currently.

How can I do that?

I get Following Error while implementing krishnabhadra's answer:

**Line at which the error comes is:**

```
[self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexVis atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

**ERROR:**

```
Assertion failure in -[NSIndexPath row], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UITableViewSupport.m:2018
2011-04-01 11:57:25.458 GlossaryPro[1525:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.'
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: currently being displayed or currently selected by user?

Comment: I asked unless your cell is so big so that it covers entire screen, more than one cells are displayed there

Comment: No cell size may be small or it may be large based on the amount of data

Comment: is it an array or a single NSIndexPath object

Comment: you need to pass on indexPath object from your array.check if you have got the correct indexPath in indexVis..

Comment: indexVis is NSIndexPath Object.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use tableView [`indexPathsForVisibleRows`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) function, which returns an `NSArray` of `NSIndexPath` for all visible `UITableViewCell`. From `indexPath.row` you can find your array index.

```
NSArray *visible       = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *indexpath = (NSIndexPath*)[visible objectAtIndex:0];
```

`indexPath.row` will give you index of first object displayed.

Comment: Thanks I will try that out soon and get back to you :)

Comment: Where should I write this code? On `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: you can call it from anywhere..Call it where you want the list of visible cells..

Comment: I scroll to some position and then switch to another tab in my tabbar and then comeback onto same tableView again, then I want that the tableView should display the same cells that It displayed before the switching. So in that case where should I write the code?

Comment: in the viewWillDisappear of the code write the above code to get the indexpath of visible array...Then in the viewWillAppear use scrollToRowAtIndexPath function of your tableView to scroll to the indexpath you saved in the array before..Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.myTableView visibleCells];

NSArray *anArrayOfIndexPath = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]];

NSIndexPath *indexPath= [anArrayOfIndexPath lastObject];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Totally and exactly what I was looking for.Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use indexPathsForVisibleRows

**Returns an array of index paths each identifying a visible row in the receiver.**

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Return Value

An array of NSIndexPath objects each representing a row index and section index that together identify a visible row in the table view. Returns nil if no rows are visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:    `[self.tableView visibleCells]`

That will return a nsarray of UITableViewCell objects, each representing a visible cell in the receiving table view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Get exact index number at center currently being displayed:

```
 let middleIndex = ((tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.row)! + (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?.row)!)/2
```

Example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let middleIndex = ((tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.row)! + (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?.row)!)/2
  print(middleIndex)

}
```