# How to get a visible top row from the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, avplayer

I should want to play video in to the `UITableView` top `cell/row`. My problem is that. How to play video into a top visible row and how to recognised the top cell of the `UITableView`, while we will scroll the `UITableView` up and down.

Comment: No, When the scrolling will stop. at the time who is cell on the top.

Comment: You can know which cell is the topmost visible by the first element returned by `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`.

Comment: @Raptor, there's no guarantee that the first element is the first visible row.

Comment: @Jeff please elaborate. (well, this question is 4 years old, the context might not be valid anymore...)

Comment: @Raptor, the documentation for `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and `visibleCells` makes no promise about the order of the elements in the returned array, so it's an unfounded assumption that the first element matches the top visible row.  The method `indexPathForRowAtPoint` would be a better way to find the top row.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative maybe. Use `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to load/initialize your video.

And in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` check the top cell using `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and play that video.

Comment: willDisplayCell is called after cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `UITableView`'s `-indexPathsForVisibleRows` or `-indexPathForRowAtPoint`.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    NSIndexPath *topVisibleIndexPath = [[self.yourtableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"top visible cell's section: %i, get row: %i", topVisibleIndexPath.section, topVisibleIndexPath.row);
}
```

for additional [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509571/how-to-get-indexpath-row-of-tableview-which-is-currently-being-displayed)

Comment: I have used it. But it is not perfectly work for me. I want to play video like as Facebook scroll page. When we scroll page then video auto play

Comment: then you need to customize something like , when your scrolling is stop u get the current /top cell index on that time you need to play the video using  web view or else and reload the current cell or reload entire cell, simple

Comment: @SankalapYadurajSingh -- any queries, when the scroll is stop on that time your cell contains video , customize the video frame and play using autoplay ,got it

Comment: Yes, i want to do it.

Comment: @SankalapYadurajSingh -- see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066713/how-to-play-video-autoplay-in-uitableview-cell, http://4byte.cn/question/467831/how-to-play-video-autoplay-in-uitableview-cell.html

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik While loading videos in scroll view delegates. Aren't there any chances that my tableview scroll gets stuck if I scroll continuosly?