# how could i detect in a UITableView, what are the cells deployed in my phone screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to figure out how to detect which `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView` are deployed in my phone screen.

For example: My numberOfRowsInSection are 20 but i see just 3 of them on the phone screen. I want to know how do determine which three are shown?

In my case, I need to send only the publicity that the users viewed in your phone screen and not the 20 rows loaded in the `UITableView`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let visibleIndexPaths = tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows

    var visibleCellsArray: [UITableViewCell] = []

    for currentIndextPath in visibleIndexPaths! {
       //  You now have visible cells in visibleCellsArray
        visibleCellsArray.append(tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(currentIndextPath)!)
    }
```

You now have visible cells in visibleCellsArray.

Comment: Translated to Swift

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method calls for the number of visible cells only.IF YOU DEQUEUE THEM.
If you want to do something based on your visible cell, either put some logic in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` which will give you back an array of visible cells and you can go on with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the `NSIndexPath` values for the rows displayed on the screen, consider the answer to [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509571/how-to-get-indexpath-row-of-tableview-which-is-currently-being-displayed).

Specifically, to get an array of the visible table cells, use:

```
self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let visibleIndexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as? [NSIndexPath]
```

This gives the array of indexPath that the cell are in visible..

i hope this will help you...